# How does value in variable reach Flat File Connection Manager and/or Flat File Source?

Tags: ssis, bids

In my `Data Flow Task` object, I have a `Flat File Source` object and an `ADO NET Destination` object. The `Flat file connection manager` in `Flat File Source` object points to file `C:\BIDS\Ssis\TextFiles\Summary_090115.txt`. That's the file that will be read when the package is run.

Since the filename will not be the same, I've added a `Foreach Loop Container` that will retrieve the filename to variable `FilePath`. So now, in `Control Flow` tab, `FilePath` should have the name of the file to read.

My question: how does the value in variable `FilePath` reach the `Flat File Connection Manager` used by `Flat File Source` object in `Data Flow` tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ConnectionString expression in the Properties menu for the FlatFile Connection manager

[This is a link from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166797.aspx)

[This is an article on how to accomplish your task](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11113/ssis-dynamically-set-flat-file-connection-manager.aspx)

1. First have a variable build a ConnectionString
2. RightClick on FlatFile Connection Manager and select Properties (alternatively select the connection manager and press F4)
3. Click on the ... next to Expressions
4. Select the Connection String Property and set it to the Variable that builds the connection string dynamically

[image: RightClick on FlatFile Connection Manager]

[image: Click on the ... next to Expressions]

[image: Select the Connection String Property]